# Whats wrong with my 2nd call to ReadINIStr?

Tags: nsis

I am a newbiew to NSIS. Trying to build a little sample that help to understand the techniques that I'd like to use in the production-installer that's build eventually...

I'd like to build a silent-installer that gets its parameter from an .INI-File with multiple section. Want to specific the section the command-line of the installer.

So, I have this NSIS-TEST.INI-File:

```
[PROD]
PATHONE=c:\Folder\Foo
AppName=My little stupid app
```

The idea is to have command-line like this:

```
FooSetup config=prod
```

The actual setup NSIS-TEST.NSI is:

```
; Script generated by the HM NIS Edit Script Wizard.
var /global REGAPPKEY
var /global PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY
; HM NIS Edit Wizard helper defines
!define REG_APPKEY ""
!define config "PROD"
!define PATHONE ""
!define PRODUCT_NAME "foo"
!define PRODUCT_VERSION "1.0"
!define PRODUCT_PUBLISHER "foo"
!define PRODUCT_WEB_SITE "http://www.example.com"
!define PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT_NAME}"
!define PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY "HKLM"

Name "${PRODUCT_NAME} ${PRODUCT_VERSION}"

OutFile "FooSetup.exe"
InstallDir "c:\foo-goo"
Icon "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Icons\modern-install.ico"
UninstallIcon "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Icons\modern-uninstall.ico"
;SilentInstall silent
;SilentUninstall silent
;InstallDirRegKey HKLM "${PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY}" ""

Section -aHauptgruppe SEC01

ReadINIStr $REGAPPKEY $INSTDIR\nsis-test.ini  ${config} "AppName"

ReadINIStr $PATHONE $INSTDIR\nsis-test.ini ${config} "PATHONE"


;MessageBox MB_ICONINFORMATION|MB_OK "config=${config}"


  ;SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"
  ;SetOverwrite ifnewer
;  File "..\..\..\pfad\zur\datei\AppMainExe.exe"
 ; CreateDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\foo"
 ; CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\foo\foo.lnk" "$INSTDIR\AppMainExe.exe"
 ; CreateShortCut "$DESKTOP\foo.lnk" "$INSTDIR\AppMainExe.exe"
 ; File "..\..\..\path\to\file\Example.file"
SectionEnd

Section -AdditionalIcons
  WriteIniStr "$INSTDIR\${PRODUCT_NAME}.url" "InternetShortcut" "URL" "${PRODUCT_WEB_SITE}"
  CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\foo\Website.lnk" "$INSTDIR\${PRODUCT_NAME}.url"
  CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\foo\Uninstall.lnk" "$INSTDIR\uninst.exe"
SectionEnd

Section -Post
  WriteUninstaller "$INSTDIR\uninst.exe"
  ;WriteRegStr HKLM "${PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY}" "" "$INSTDIR\AppMainExe.exe"
  ;WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "DisplayName" "$(^Name)"
  ;WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "UninstallString" "$INSTDIR\uninst.exe"
  ;WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "DisplayIcon" "$INSTDIR\AppMainExe.exe"
  ;WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "DisplayVersion" "${PRODUCT_VERSION}"
  ;WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "URLInfoAbout" "${PRODUCT_WEB_SITE}"
  ;WriteRegStr ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}" "Publisher" "${PRODUCT_PUBLISHER}"
SectionEnd


Function un.onUninstSuccess
  MessageBox MB_ICONINFORMATION|MB_OK "$(^Name) wurde erfolgreich deinstalliert."
FunctionEnd

Function un.onInit
  MessageBox MB_ICONQUESTION|MB_YESNO|MB_DEFBUTTON2 "M�chten Sie $(^Name) und alle seinen Komponenten deinstallieren?" IDYES +2
  Abort
FunctionEnd

Section Uninstall
  Delete "$INSTDIR\${PRODUCT_NAME}.url"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\uninst.exe"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\Example.file"
  Delete "$INSTDIR\AppMainExe.exe"

  Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\foo\Uninstall.lnk"
  Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\foo\Website.lnk"
  Delete "$DESKTOP\foo.lnk"
  Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\foo\foo.lnk"

  RMDir "$SMPROGRAMS\foo"
  RMDir "$INSTDIR"

  DeleteRegKey ${PRODUCT_UNINST_ROOT_KEY} "${PRODUCT_UNINST_KEY}"
  ;DeleteRegKey HKLM "${PRODUCT_DIR_REGKEY}"
  SetAutoClose true
SectionEnd

FooSetup config=prod
```

If I compile this, the last lines of the output are:

```
Section: "-aHauptgruppe" ->(SEC01)
ReadINIStr $REGAPPKEY [PROD]:AppName from $INSTDIR\nsis-test.ini

Usage: ReadINIStr $(user_var: output) ini_file section entry_name
Error in script "c:\blabla\setup2019\nsis-test.nsi" on line 29 -- aborting creation process
```

So it has processed the first of my `ReadINIStr`-Instructions and barfed on the second one. I have looked at this code for hours, have injected line-feed etc., but I can't see what's so different about the 2nd instruction...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$PATHONE` is not a variable. You're missing:

```
Var PATHONE
```

Note you do have:

```
!define PATHONE ""
```

So be careful not getting the two confused.